# How to recover a real irreducible representation from its complexification?

Tags: representation-theory

Suppose that I know $V_\mathbb{R}$ is an irreducible representation of real semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R}$. But I only know $\mathfrak{g}_\mathbb{R}$ and $V_\mathbb{R}\otimes \mathbb{C}$. How can I recover $V_\mathbb{R}$ from this information?